# How to have corectly scaled intervals on the same line with some text?

Tags: math-mode, scaling

I want the (-infty, -b/2a] interval to be scaled as the big one, but, at the same time, to came in line after the text. The one that's with the text is smaller. How can I remediate this?

[image]

Comment: Add `\displaystyle` command before your `\frac`

Comment: Please never ever just show images of your code. No one wants to re-type your code in order to test it.

Answer (score 1):

On suggestion of the user @koleygr.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
Never use double dollar for an equation!
\begin{enumerate}
     \item $a>0 \implies $ \ldots pe $\displaystyle\left(-\infty, -\frac{b}{2a}\right]$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! What does display style change and why shouldn't I use $$ sign for equations?

Comment: @EmilianPopa You can read here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to